# Steam is missing following 32-bit libraries, and steam may not run

Tags: steam

I have recently installed Ubuntu desktop version 23.10 and attempted to download and install Steam. However, when I go to launch Steam it gives me the following message:

`Steam is missing the following 32-bit libraries, and steam cannot run: Libc.so.6`

All other posts here relating to Steam giving this error with this package or other packages have yet to solve this issue, please help.

Architecture details: aarch64

Comment: You've not provided any *architecture* details; but `libc6 | 2.38-1ubuntu6    | mantic          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` shows it available for both 32-bit ARM & 32-bit x86

Comment: If you install steam from the standard repositories, all the dependencies should be installed also. sudo apt install steam should get what is needed.